# How to get value in object type list C#

Tags: c#, object

I have a `System.object` type `list`.
I can't use [0] or [1],... to get value because it is object.

I tried `GetType()` and use many functions, but didn't work.

Is there any way to read it?

I write a function can convert any object, convert means validate or something.

```
  private static IDictionary<string, object> objectConvert(object data)
    {
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    var attrs = data.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var attr in attrs)
        {
           // if attribute is object do something (use  use recursion )...
           // if attribute is list do something (use recursion)...
           // if not object or list, just add to result
           // after all return result
        }
    }
```

Attribute is object I work well, but when it is list I tried so hard but can't get any element in list object.

Comment: Why do you have it as `object`, not `List<T>`?

Comment: I'm afraid 'system.object type list' doesn't really make sense as you've explained it. Can you post your code?

Comment: I think he has a List<T> kind of thing in an Object type variable.

Comment: -1 You need to provide some code.

Comment: I provided some code.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast it. Use `as` so that it is `null` if the cast fails and check it:

```
var list = yourObjectInstance as IList<type_here>();

if (list != null) {
    // cast successful.
}
```

Comment: No, object is a variable, you dont know type

Answer (score 0):

If you know the actual type of your object, simply cast it to that type using standard casting. You can then use indexer on it like `((List<T>)YourObject)[0]`.

Comment: No, it's any object, can't know actual entity